# Find specific words and replace with capitals

Tags: regex, unix, awk, gsub

I need to use Unix and create an awk script. The first part of the script is to find the words "Ant" "Ass" and "Ape" in a text file and replace them with the same word but capitalized.

Do I use gsub to find each occurrence? If i do:

```
{gsub(/Ass/, "ASS"); print}
{gsub(/Ape/, "APE"); print}
{gsub(/Ant/, 'ANT"); print}
```

it just prints every line of the file 3 or 4 times... how can I search and replace these three words and then print out only the modified line?

---

The second part of the program is to track the number of lines with matches to Ass, Ape, or Ant and the number of substitutions made.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all the substitutions in a single clause:

```
{subs += gsub(/Ass/, "ASS"); subs += gsub(/Ape/, "APE"); subs += gsub(/Ant/, "ANT"); print; }
END { print "Total substitutions:", subs; }
```

Comment: Thank you! That works!! But now my code prints the original line as well as the changed line... (check out this screenshot: http://jcsites.juniata.edu/students/caulehe11/Capture.png)

Also, thanks for the count of subs! Do you know how I can keep track of the number of lines with those words on them?

Comment: It doesn't print the original line for me. Are you typing the input interactively? You're seeing your typing mixed with the output.

Comment: if you want to know if any changes were made on the line, use a new variable to hold the results of `gsub`, and check whether it's more than 0 after all the substitutions. Then you can increment a `lines_changed` variable, and add this per-line total to `subs` for the running total.

Comment: I'm using a text file and running the awk script then outputting to another file. In that new file, there's the original line and the new one... ex of my command: nawk -f myreplace.awk aesop.txt > aesop2.txt

Comment: I just tried my script that way and it worked perfectly, the original is not printed.

Comment: It's because in my script, I have two things going on before I do the word sub... 

NF>0 to remove blank lines and a regex search for lines with only capital letters to put 30 hyphens under them... when I removed these two parts of the script, it worked and only printed the new line... Do you know how I can incorporate the first parts but still only print once? Can I only have one print statement per line?

Comment: Give those other clauses an action of `0` to prevent them from printing.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed 's/Ant/ANT/g; s/Ass/ASS/g; s/Ape/APE/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
awk  '
  BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1}
  { 
      s = 0
      while (match(substr($0, s),/ass|ape|ant/) > 0) {
          c=substr($0,s + RSTART - 1,RLENGTH)
          sub(c,toupper(c))
          s += RSTART + RLENGTH
      }
     print
   }' input
```